# View/Controller separation with a programmatic view

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, uiview, nib

I am making a UIView-based class for use as a tableHeaderView.  It will have several controls that will be based on edit mode - some will appear/disappear and some will change appearance when it switches modes.  The height of the view itself will change when it switches modes.  Seeing that the layout will change a lot, I decided it would be better to just make the whole thing programmatically than to try to lay it out in a nib.

What I am struggling with is where the view/controller separation should be.  Should the viewcontroller have an object for each control (UITextField, UISegmentedControl, UIButton, etc) or should it just have an instance of my UIView-based class?

Where should the code that actually creates the controls and sets the properties reside?  Should my view have a method that gets called to set the entire view (based on edit mode) or does this put too much power in the view that should be in the controller? Should the view only set the positions of the controls?  Or should there not even be a UIView-based class - the view controller will declare and configure all the controls by itself?

What is the proper MVC separation here?

jorj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC rule of thumb is that your controller is the go-between – if your model is storing information about the edit mode, then your code will be cleaner if the controller does the work. If the edit mode settings are discarded when the view goes away, then the controller doesn't need to know about them.

It's also worth considering whether this code will be re-used – if you're creating a view that you're going to use again elsewhere, that may make it easier to decide where the "brains" of the code should reside.